# loading classes from custom dependency in a custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a custom Gradle plugin, that works well, I have published a couple of versions already.

I have a new requirement, where I want to allow the plugin's users to provide an optional list of dependencies, in which they would provide classes, that can be loaded during the plugin execution.

Looking at the documentation, it seems to be quite close to what is described in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#providing_default_dependencies_for_plugins (in my case there's no default though - or said differently, the default should be an empty list of extra dependencies), but I struggle to adapt it to my use case.

right now, my plugin can be configured like this :

```
archUnit {

  preConfiguredRules = ["sample.SampleRule"]

}
```

the plugin already contains some rules, but I want to allow users to provide their own rules, they should be able to provide something like

```
dependencies {
  archUnitDeps 'org.example:archunit-custom-rules:1.0'
}
```

if the provided class (`sample.SampleRule`) is in that extra dependency that we configure, the plugin should load it and apply it, just like it does with the rules that are currently packaged with the plugin.

Following the docs, I create a configuration in my plugin :

```
   Configuration deps = project.getConfigurations().create("archUnitDeps", c -> {
        c.setVisible(false);
        c.setCanBeConsumed(false);
        c.setCanBeResolved(true);
        c.setDescription("The packaged extra rules you may want to add ");
      });
```

but then what should I do ?

I've tried something like this, to get the dependencies that the user configures, and add them at project level :

```
    DependencyHandler dependencies = project.getDependencies();

    deps.getAllDependencies().stream().forEach( extraDep -> dependencies.create(extraDep));
```

but when using it in a project, `deps.getAllDependencies()` is empty, even though I configure the `org.example:archunit-custom-rules:1.0` dependency as above. So nothing gets loaded, and I end up with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.SampleRule`.

what am I missing ? do you have a readily available example of a plugin that does something similar, that I could get inspiration from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to solve this, thanks to the help I got on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/class-loaded-through-configuration-is-not-found-when-task-runs/42945/3

I am quite surprised there's not a simpler solution, but one way of doing, is to use Gradle worker API, which takes 2 main steps :

1. in the task, get access to the `workQueue`, and submit the parameters required for the task execution :

```java
    WorkQueue queue = getWorkerExecutor().classLoaderIsolation(spec -> spec.getClasspath().from(getClasspath()));
            queue.submit(WorkerAction.class, params -> {
                params.getMainClassesPath().set(someValue);
                params.getTestClassesPath().set(someOtherValue);
                etc.. 
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            });
```

2. On the worker side, get back those parameters, and launch what you were initially doing in the task :

```java
public abstract class WorkerAction implements WorkAction<WorkerActionParams> {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        WorkerActionParams params = getParameters();

       ....
    }
```

The parameters you pass need to be serializable - I was not able to make that part fully work with my original parameters, so I had to create new "wrapper" ones.

full example is available here : https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-gradle-plugin/pull/24/files